# How to make content of page not centered vertically?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

My pages are vertically centered by default:
[image]

the code has no /vfill or /vspace{fill} so im not sure what the issue is

The code:

```
\documentclass{gradthesis}

\begin{document}
    \printcoverpage

    \begin{abstract}
        \vspace{1cm}
        Abstract
    \end{abstract}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \thesisTOF
    \newpage
    \thesisTOT
    
    \newpage
    \input{chapters/chapter1}
    
    \newpage
    \input{chapters/chapter2}
    
    \newpage
    \input{chapters/chapter3}
    
    \bibliography{references}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\end{document}
```

The gradthesis.cls file:

```
\def\lxdef{\long\xdef}
\def\@classname {gradthesis}

\LoadClass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{natbib}
\RequirePackage[table,figure]{totalcount}
\RequirePackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\gdef\@templateVersion{1.0.0}
\gdef\@templateDate{06/02/2021}
\gdef\@templateAuthor{Dania Alaaeldin}

\ProvidesClass{\@classname}[\@templateDate \@templateVersion \@templateAuthor]

\graphicspath{ {./logos/} }

\lxdef \@universityname {October University for Modern Sciences and Arts}
\newcommand{\universityname}[1]{\xdef\@universityname{#1}}
\lxdef \@facultyname {Faculty of Computer Science}
\newcommand{\facultyname}[1]{\xdef\@facultyname{#1}}
\lxdef \@subtitle {Graduation Project Thesis}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{\xdef\@subtitle{#1}}
\lxdef \@authorid {182967}
\newcommand{\authorid}[1]{\xdef\@authorid{#1}}
\lxdef \@supervisor {Supervised By: Dr. Ahmed Farouk}
\newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\xdef\@supervisor{#1}}
\lxdef \@docdate {Fall 2020}
\newcommand{\docdate}[1]{\xdef\@docdate{#1}}
\lxdef \@thesistitle {3D Segmentation and Automated 2D Sketching Tutorials}
\newcommand{\thesistitle}[1]{\xdef\@thesistitle{#1}}
\lxdef \@thesisauthor {Dania Alaaeldin}
\newcommand{\thesisauthor}[1]{\xdef\@thesisauthor{#1}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\@thesistitle}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\roman{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\newcommand{\thesisTOF}{
    \iftotalfigures
        \cleardoublepage
        \listoffigures
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\thesisTOT}{
    \iftotaltables
        \cleardoublepage
        \listoftables
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\@coverpage}{
    \begin{titlepage}
    
        \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{msalogo} \hspace{0.4cm}
            \includegraphics[width=2.3in, height=0.7in]{greenwichlogo} \hspace{0.5cm}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{cslogo}
            
            \vspace{3.5cm}
            {\large \@subtitle \par \vspace{1cm}}
            {\LARGE \textbf{\@thesistitle} \par}
            \vspace{1cm}
            {\Large \@thesisauthor \par}
            {\large \@authorid \par}
            \vspace{0.45cm}
            {\large \@supervisor \par}
            \vspace{3.5cm}
        
            {\@universityname \par \vspace{0.25cm} \@facultyname \par \vspace{0.25cm} \@docdate}
    
    \end{titlepage}
}

\newcommand{\printcoverpage}{
    \@coverpage
}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) While I strongly suspect that some user here might be able to read minds `:-)`, unfortunately most of us can't, and we actually need to look at some code. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: @campa sorry about that haha, edited!

Comment: better but we still can not run it as all in input files failed, but presumably they are needed to show the problem and you could replace them all with `\chapter{zzz} hello world`  in the main file?

Comment: the class gives an error `! LaTeX3 Error: First argument of '\RenewDocumentCommand' must be a command.` after any error the PDF is not intended to be usable

Comment: If I delete the bad definition at the end of the class and replace all the \input by `\chapter{zzz}\section{abc}` then I do not get a vertically centred page: [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKY5e.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not sure i completely get what you mean by bad definition, what do i need to show you so that you can better see why my page is centered vertically?

Comment: tex stops with an error on every use of that class file because at the end it has `\RenewDocumentCommand{}` which is claiming to define a command but not specifying the name to define. If I may I could update your example so it is usable (the one I used to make the above image)  Then you can further edit so it shows the problem.

Comment: If you run the code as it is now, I see no problem with the output. If your real document is showing vertical centred pages please edit the example so it shows the problem, but keeping it so that we can run it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my abstract page is centered in the provided page, as for the error, i wasnt sure how to call my coverpage

Comment: but the class is not usable at all if it gives an error while loading

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I updated it and removed the error! but abstract is still vertically centered

Comment: yes sorry I was looking at the toc, that is the default for report class titlepages, you can put `\@titlepagefalse` or load report with `[notitlepage]` in your class.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle perfect! thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is based on the standard `report` class and by default title pages and abstract are vertically centered.

the report class has a `[notitlepage]` option to not do this or equivalently you can use `\@titlepagefalse` within your class to disable this behaviour, either everywhere or just for the abstract.